# looping and comparing arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, contains

I am trying to loop through a file and match each string on each line to elements in an array list. I am not able to get a loop to work for the array list. It is only pulling the first element from the list.

```
   array1 = new String[] {"hello", "goodbye"};
   while ((file = br.readLine()) != null) {
             String compare = Character.toString(file.charAt(0)) 
                     + Character.toString(file.charAt(1));


             for(int i=0;i<array1.length; i++) {
                boolean ret = Arrays.asList(compare).contains(array1[i]);
                System.out.println(ret);
             }

   }
   br.close();
```

Comment: Can you show some of the contents of the file?  Also, why only compare with the first two characters of the line?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why its failing but you are only comparing with the first two characters in each line of the file and in your example the two characters in your array are more than 2 characters.

A better way to achieve what you are trying to do is uisng hashmap, key should be the string you want to check if exists in your list so all you need to do instead of your for loop is

```
         System.out.println(map.get(compare) != null);
```

Answer (score -1):

you already are using the for-loop so you can initialize i in for (int i = 0; ...) { } and you dont need to increment i at the end, because again you already are doing this in your for-statement.

i am not sure why your list-check is just executed for one word but your compare will just be a word of two characters... are you sure this is correct?

Comment: For such small additions , you can yourself edit the question or add the comment , and you have not provided the answer as well , for any Questions please leave a comment on the question